# Access 2003 VBA: custom form property problem

Tags: ms-access, forms, vba

I have a regular form called "Fish". It has a TreeCtl called "loctree" which I used as a location chooser to change a field in Fish.

I've since added several subforms to Fish. Two of these have location fields that I would like to use loctree for. Since I didn't want to instantiate a new TreeCtl for each of these subforms, I thought I could just let loctree know which control its current target is. I thought the easiest way to define the current target would be to add a property to my Fish form:

```
Option Compare Database

Private locfield As Field

Property Let loc_focusField(target As Field)
    locfield = target
End Property

Property Get loc_focusField()
    loc_focusField = locfield
End Property
```

And then in the Open Event for the Fish form, I could set the default value of locfield:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  locfield = Forms!fish_moves!fish_moves_loc_id
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, every time I try to open my form I get the following error:

> Definitions of property procedures for
>   the same property are inconsistent, or
>   property procedure has an optional
>   parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid
>   Set final parameter

So what gives?

Thanks,
Jen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, your properties should look like

```
Property Set loc_focusField(target As Field)
    set locfield = target
End Property

Property Get loc_focusField() as Field
    set loc_focusField = locfield
End Property
```

Does that work?